# array within an if - custom post types - Wordpress functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the code below to strip bits and pieces from the Wordpress posts display & the publish metaboxes for different post types. The code as it is all works, I'm just wondering if it could succesfully be squashed down into a single array? I'm not sure how to do that.

I'd appreciate any help anyone could give.

```
function hide_publishing_actions(){
        global $post;

        if($post->post_type == 'page'){
            echo '
                <style type="text/css">
                    #misc-publishing-actions,
                    #minor-publishing-actions,
                    ul.subsubsub,
                    p.search-box,
                    div.view-switch,
                    #posts-filter .tablenav select[name=m],
                    #posts-filter .tablenav #post-query-submit{
                        display:none;
                    }
                </style>
            ';
        }

        if($post->post_type == 'post-type-1'){
            echo '
                <style type="text/css">
                    #misc-publishing-actions,
                    #minor-publishing-actions,
                    ul.subsubsub,
                    p.search-box,
                    div.view-switch,
                    #posts-filter .tablenav select[name=m],
                    #posts-filter .tablenav #post-query-submit{
                        display:none;
                    }
                </style>
            ';
        }

        if($post->post_type == 'post-type-2'){
            echo '
                <style type="text/css">
                    #misc-publishing-actions,
                    #minor-publishing-actions,
                    ul.subsubsub,
                    p.search-box,
                    div.view-switch,
                    #posts-filter .tablenav select[name=m],
                    #posts-filter .tablenav #post-query-submit{
                        display:none;
                    }
                </style>
            ';
        }


        if($post->post_type == 'post-type-3'){
            echo '
                <style type="text/css">
                    #misc-publishing-actions,
                    #minor-publishing-actions,
                    ul.subsubsub,
                    p.search-box,
                    div.view-switch,
                    #posts-filter .tablenav select[name=m],
                    #posts-filter .tablenav #post-query-submit{
                        display:none;
                    }
                </style>
            ';
        }        

        if($post->post_type == 'post-type-3'){
            echo '
                <style type="text/css">
                    #misc-publishing-actions,
                    #minor-publishing-actions,
                    ul.subsubsub,
                    p.search-box,
                    div.view-switch,
                    #posts-filter .tablenav select[name=m],
                    #posts-filter .tablenav #post-query-submit{
                        display:none;
                    }
                </style>
            ';
        }        

        if($post->post_type == 'post-type-4'){
            echo '
                <style type="text/css">
                    #misc-publishing-actions,
                    #minor-publishing-actions,
                    ul.subsubsub,
                    p.search-box,
                    div.view-switch,
                    #posts-filter .tablenav select[name=m],
                    #posts-filter .tablenav #post-query-submit{
                        display:none;
                    }
                </style>
            ';
        }        
}
add_action('admin_head-post.php', 'hide_publishing_actions');
add_action('admin_head-post-new.php', 'hide_publishing_actions');
add_action('admin_head-edit.php', 'hide_publishing_actions');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of separate if statements, use `in_array()` to combine in to one if statement.

See: https://www.php.net/in_array

```
if(in_array($post->post_type, array('page', 'post-type-1', 'post-type-2', 'post-type-3', 'post-type-4')) { ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - appreciate it. When I try this I just get a white screen though.

Comment: ...or you can use the logical OR (denoted as ||) operator in your if() condition: if ($post->post_type == 'post-type-1' || $post->post_type == 'post-type-2' || etc...)